# Modelica Reduction Method Pantelides error in electrical due to missing ground

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm posting this for anyone who runs into the same problem in the future.  I was running into a problem running the following simple electrical model:

[image]

It produces the following error:

```
[1] 16:14:41 Translation Error
Internal error Circular Equalities Detected for Variables:
----------------------------------

[2] 16:14:41 Translation Error
Internal error IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction failed! Found empty set of continuous equations. Use -d=bltdump to get more information.

[3] 16:14:41 Translation Error
Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modelica references everything internally to ground, which is not defined here.  Every isolated electrical network will need to be referenced to ground.  To correct this problem I added a ground connection as follows:

[image]

Comment: This applies to other physical domains as well. In hydraulic systems, for example, most components only describe the relationship between *changes* in pressure (potential) and flow. Thus, a reference pressure ("ground") must be defined somewhere in the model.

Comment: However, even if there are similar concepts in other physical domains they are not the identical. You can have a hydraulic component with absolute pressure (and components to store excess fluids - with no obvious electrical counterpart), and mechanical systems are different again (even the "world" object is different than ground).

Comment: @Jonathan, Just curious how did you figure out we should add ground.. it's not obvious from the error!

Comment: @tiredandboreddev It has to do with how equations are formed on electrical components.  If you take a look at the underlying code, each terminal has an associated voltage (.v) and current (.i).  The terminal voltages are relative to ground.  Therefore, if nothing is referenced to ground, the translator will determine that the system is not solvable.  Other, tools, such as Matlab, don't require a ground reference, but this is probably because voltages are only referenced to other connections or "nets" when translating the model.

Comment: Thanks. This explanation saved lot of time!!